# Focus on a text field programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<input type="text" id="text_box1" >
```

I need to set focus on this field programmatically.

What i tried from the console( after the page has loaded) doesn't seem to work.

```
1) $('#text_box1').focus();
2) document.getElementById("text_box1").focus();
```

Any idea on what is wrong here?

I am using jQuery 1.11.3

Comment: just a note: why are you using such a prehistoric version of jQuery?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsbin.com/ravidiwani/edit?html,js,output). Is it possible you have (gasp) another element that _also_ has ID `text_box1`?

Comment: make sure you have putted that function inside a document.ready

Answer (score 3):

It works! It must be called once after loading the `DOM`.

The below function will be called after the `DOM` are loaded

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
     //any other code which needs to be called after the DOM is completely loaded
});
```

Similary, with Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
}
```

```js
$(function(){

$('#text_box1').focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text_box1" >
```

Answer (score 0):

just use autofocus attributein form field...

```
<input type="text" id="text_box1" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JavaScript function, it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () 
{
document.getElementById("text_box1").focus();
};
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Window.Onload - Fires when the entire page loads, including its content (images, css, scripts, etc.) & document.onload - Fires when the DOM is ready which can be prior to images and other external content is loaded.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include this explanation